# Ember Validation on models

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, email-validation

As, I am using lots of models in my application, there are the cases like, I have to include 2 more models in the route and I merge them using RSVP. I used previously objectcontroller and now I am changing it to controllers... I'd like to replace my validations object from my controller to the models so that I don't have to use model.modelname.property....

Please tell me like is it possible to replace from the controllers to models?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [Ember Validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations) does exactly what you want. Please see Brian Cardarella's article entitled [Understanding validation graphs](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/04/30/understanding-validation-graphs.html) for an overview.